# Store and retrieve corresponding items

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary

I have program in which I wrote custom classes for some purpose. I need to store the classes in the form of a `map` like data structure where I can easily get an item corresponding to the other. For eg:

```
class Rectangle{
//...
};
class ShapeContainer{
//...};
class WarpedRectangle{
//...
};
class Adorner{
//...
};
```

The above are three different classes and in my program, I try to do the things as follows: (taking the example of `map` here since it is the most close)
map _inputOutputMap;
map _inputWarpedMap;
map _adornerWarpedMap;

**Operation 1**:
_inputOutputMap[inputRectangle1] = &shapeContainer1;
**Operation 2**:
_inputWarpedMap[inputRectangle1] = &warpedRectangle1;
**Operation 3**:
return _inputWarpedMap[inputRectangle1]
**Operation 4**:
_adornerWarpedMap[adorner1] = &warpedRectangle1;
**Operation 5**:
return _adornerWarpedMap[adorner1]

Note that the intent of using the `map` is not to get any sort order, comparison or such but to just to keep a correspondence between various items [for this input, that is the output etc.]. If I try to go ahead using the map itself, I get an errors somewhere in stl_function.h (function: `struct less : public binary_function<_Tp, _Tp, bool>`) during the compile time with highlighted message:
**Invalid operands to binary expression (const Adorner and const Adorner) etc.**

How can I get this type of correspondence and lookup properties for my requirement?

Comment: Have you defined a comparison operation for `Adorner` etc?

Comment: @n.m. : How would we define equality operation for shapes classes?

Comment: @n.m. And some of the shapes are not defined by me. These are directly used classes from the framework.

Comment: Are you asking me? `std::map` requires your keys to be *ordered* (that is. not just the equality, but the less-than operation too). The compiler tells you that it cannot compare two `Adorner` objects. It needs to, because that's how `std::map` works. If you cannot make comparison work, you cannot use `std::map`.

Comment: As the answer says, with `unordered_map` you can get away without less-than, but you still need equality. But I suspect you might really want something else. If you cannot compare two shapes for equality, but you somehow know that shape X should be indexed by shape Y and not by shape Z, this could indicate that you are using *pointer identity* instead of *value identity*, and therefore your key in the map should be a *pointer* to `Adorner` etc. This is just a guess which may be correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `std::unordered_map`?  Should be faster than `std::map` for this use case anyway.

(Note that you will still need to ensure that the key objects support an equality comparison for this to work, or you need to provide an external predicate function that does the same thing).

Comment: @mwigdahi: I am not sure how could we define equality operation for shapes classes for example. Could you throw some light?

Comment: Well, you're using them as keys in the map, which means that you need to have some way to indicate that one key is the same as another key, hence an equality test.  You would define an `operator == ()` for the class and compare whatever internal state defines your shape object, and if the internal state matches you return true.

Comment: And some of the shapes are not defined by me. These are directly used classes from the framework. Rectangle for example is used at numerous places in the whole code and even if equality operator is added for Rectangle somehow, there are other places in the code for which it won't make sense. Is there a way out?

Comment: For example, if you wanted to compare two rectangles, you'd look at their origin points, lengths, and widths, and if they were the same, you'd return true. If the rectangle also had a property such as color that was relevant to the comparison, you'd also include a check to ensure color matched. The precise details are determined by your implementation.

Comment: You don't need to modify the classes directly -- unordered_map allows you to specify a comparison predicate function that is external to your key class.  Check the signature here:  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/

Comment: @mwigdahl: that site is notoriously inaccurate, please use [this other site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).